# MacPorts can't recognize Xcode version properly

Tags: macos, xcode, macports

I've tried to run the following command to install "automake" package on my Mac:

```
MacBook:~ administrator$ sudo port install automake
Password:
Error: The installed version of Xcode (5.1.1) is too old to use on the installed OS version. Version 6.1 or later is recommended on Mac OS X 10.10.
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port automake failed
```

The problem is shown in the line:

> Error: The installed version of Xcode (5.1.1) is too old to use on the
>   installed OS version. Version 6.1 or later is recommended on Mac OS X
>   10.10.

But there is Xcode 6.1 installed on my Mac. I'm using OS X 10.10 Yosemite (MacPorts for 10.10 already installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `xcode-select --switch [path]` as descriped here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600615/xcode-stops-working-after-set-xcode-select-switch

And here is Apples documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this frustrating situation as well. Reinstalling Xcode 6.1 and then running 'xcode-select' solved the problem.